# Pass items with different tenant SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have two different SharePoint online sites **(Site1 & site2)**.

When an item(Calendar List) is added into Site1 it should automatically added to Site2 also.

Is there any solution for adding item from tenant to tenant site level?

Comment: Only custom, create and using Event Reciever.

Comment: Hello @MelviN - As you are suggesting Event Receiver, I will try once with remote event receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Flow, you can actually capture event (item added) from site 1 and you can trigger this to another action (SharePoint - item create) which will create the item in the calendar in site 2.

Microsoft flow allows you to add a new connection (tenant permission) to configure on each step so you can enter different credentials for each connection.

[image]

Comment: Oh really!!! by using MS Flows we can insert item from one tenant to another tenant site level? (**both parent are different so am asking**).

Comment: yes @sathish .  I did experiment it as well.